# ASUS X200MA boot failure and can't edit the BIOS settings

Tags: windows-7, windows

An [ASUS X200MA](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X200MA/) notebook fails to boot windows, and I cannot change the BIOS settings. Instead, it constantly reboots.

Comment: Still under warranty? Then I would not open it, and instead contact support at https://vip.asus.com/VIP2/Services/TechQuery?lang=en-us . Please advise if you needs a post-warranty solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Your PC's manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X200MA/0409_E8798_A.pdf) suggests using F2 to get into the BIOS as soon as any text first appears on the display. If you carefully remove the hard drive, typically requiring only one screw on the underside, then it can't get into Windows, and you can get into the BIOS with F2.

When you carefully remove the hard drive, use a [USB-SATA adapter](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2036718/why-its-a-good-idea-to-own-a-usb-to-sata-adapter.html) to attach the drive to another PC and back up your data, just in case.